# Remove Content type header when making an http request

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers

I have been trying to upload form-data, but I do not want to send any Content-Type header. I have tried setting

```
headers: {
           'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
           'Content-Type': undefined
         }
```

But the request still contains

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykplXRCRn92v5Op52
```

The code block for reference :

```
$http({
    url: "/file/",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        'file': res
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
})
```

I am unable to understand what exactly is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I understand what is multipart-form data. I just need to strip off that header.

Comment: What happens if you use `'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'` or `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'`? The AngularJS default Content-Type is application/json; When I set the Content-Type to `undefined`, my browser (Chrome) inserts `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
`

Comment: @georgeawg I tried setting it to 'application/json', but since I am sending multipart form data, it somehow changes the header. And I doubt if its being done by the browser.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why you don't want the Content-Type field.