# Paw - How do I disable Content-Type header?

Tags: paw-app

I'm testing an API that won't work if `Content-Type` HTTP header is provided, the request look like this:

```
# this works
curl -X "POST" "https://example.com" \
     -d "text=text content"
```

If I create this request in [Paw](https://paw.cloud), `Content-Type` is automatically added and the request becomes

```
# this doesn't work for this API
curl -X "POST" "https://example.com" \
     -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' \
     -d "text=text content"
```

So how do I disable the `Content-Type` header? Setting it with an empty value doesn't work either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567592/remove-content-type-header-when-making-an-http-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paw has an "Automatically Send Content-Type Header" option under Preferences -> Network.

[image: paw preferences, network tab]